# Pygame, spawning an infinite number of enemies?

Tags: python, class, pygame

I am making a game in pygame, and I know how to make the class that will spawn the enemy in a random spot, make it move randomly, and attack of the player gets near, but I don't know how to reuse this class an infinite amount of times. How do i create an arbitrary number of instances of a class?

Comment: Show us some code? How do you spawn enemies at the moment? What tutorial did you follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong with creating an instance of the class and throwing it in a list?

```
entity_list = []
for i in range(10000000):
   entity_list.append(Entity())
```